# How to get element by key and replace it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have some list

```
tests = [
{'module': 'module1', 'test': 'test1', 'v8': 'pass'},
{'module': 'module2', 'test': 'test2', 'v8': 'fail'},
{'module': 'module3', 'test': 'test3', 'v8': 'fail'}
]
```

How I can get element 'v8' where 'test' equals test1, and replace it with other value?

Comment: Please do not name lists `list` it overrides a builtin python name.

Comment: rebuild using list comprehension.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @chrisz, yeh, thank you,I know about it. I wrote this for example only

Answer (score 3):

*(you shouldn't use `list` as a name as it overrides the `list()` function, so I replaced it with `l`)*

---

Just iterate over the list and replace where appropriate:

```
for d in l:
    if d['test'] == 'test1':
        d['v8'] = 'another'
```

giving:

```
[{'test': 'test1', 'v8': 'another', 'module': 'module1'},
 {'test': 'test2', 'v8': 'fail', 'module': 'module2'},
 {'test': 'test3', 'v8': 'fail', 'module': 'module3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> tests = [
... {'module': 'module1', 'test': 'test1', 'v8': 'pass'},
... {'module': 'module2', 'test': 'test2', 'v8': 'fail'},
... {'module': 'module3', 'test': 'test3', 'v8': 'fail'}
... ]
```

First, extract the item you need.

```
>>> item = [d for d in tests if d['test'] == 'test1']
>>> item
[{'v8': 'pass', 'module': 'module1', 'test': 'test1'}]
```

You have a list of one element; check access to field `v8`

```
>>> item[0]['v8']
'pass'
```

Now, simply reassign that field.

```
>>> item[0]['v8'] = "NEW VALUE"
>>> item
[{'v8': 'NEW VALUE', 'module': 'module1', 'test': 'test1'}]
>>> tests
[{'v8': 'NEW VALUE', 'module': 'module1', 'test': 'test1'}, {'v8': 'fail', 'module': 'module2', 'test': 'test2'}, {'v8': 'fail', 'module': 'module3', 'test': 'test3'}]
```

Note that the value of the original dict changes: this happens with references to mutable items.  Go through enough tutorials that you *understand* this before you try to make further use of it.